# for (... in ...) loop not working in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, iteration

I'm learning to use `mysql` module in node.js, so I use it with `Express` & `Mustache` to render a MySQL table and came up with this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var mu2 = require('mu2');
mu2.root = __dirname + '/views';

var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    port: 3306,
    database: 'breakthrough'
});

con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error connecting to database:\n' + err);
        return;
    }
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var tableHTML;
    function renderTable(rows) {
        tableHTML = "<table>";
        for (var row in rows) {
            tableHTML += "<tr>";
            for (var cell in row) {
                tableHTML += ("<td>" + cell + "</td>");
            }
            tableHTML += "</tr>";
        }
        tableHTML += '</table>';
    }
    con.query('SELECT * FROM drivers', function (err, rows){
        if (err) { throw(err); }
        renderTable(rows);
        htmlStream = mu2.compileAndRender('frontPage.html', {table: tableHTML});
        htmlStream.pipe(res);
    });
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port 8080.");
});
```

But the resulting table only show zeroes, one for each row:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>0</td></tr>
    <!-- tr repeated for each row in rows -->
</table>
```

Some readings suggest that iterating over objects in node.js is currently quite problematic. Is there any way I can lazy-iterate over node.js objects?

Comment: `cell` is the index. If you want the contents, you need to print `row[cell]` (and also iterate over `rows[row]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that rows is an array (according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) so when you doing :

```
for(var row in rows)
```

row take only the index and not the value, that's why your second for loop is wrong. In addition take only the index and not the value

Change it to :

```
for (var row in rows) {
    tableHTML += "<tr>";
    for (var cell in rows[row]) {
        tableHTML += ("<td>" + rows[row][cell] + "</td>");
    }
    tableHTML += "</tr>";
}
```

But looping over an array using for in isn't a good idea, see [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Use :

```
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         tableHTML += "<tr>";
         for (var cell in rows[i]) {
            tableHTML += ("<td>" + rows[i][cell] + "</td>");
         }
         tableHTML += "</tr>";
      }
```